Why does the prompt "give me top 3 services" for 'gpt-35-turbo-16k' trigger Azure OpenAI's content management policy 'Sexual (medium)'
We are working on a NLP-to-SQL POC. While submitting a prompt to Azure Open AI we are facing a strange error. We have narrowed it down to the prompt 'give me top 3 services'. Please see the screenshot below:
(https://i.sstatic.net/cYHJd.png)
When I submit the prompt 'give me top 3 services' to standard deployment of 'gpt-35-turbo-16k' in Azure, it gives me an error saying:
"The prompt was filtered due to triggering Azure OpenAI’s content filtering system.
Reason: This prompt contains content flagged as Sexual (medium)"
Don't understand why it's giving me this error and how to solve it?
When I ask "is there anything offensive or sexual in 'give me top 3 services'" all I get back is:
"The prompt was filtered due to triggering Azure OpenAI’s content filtering system.
Reason: This prompt contains content flagged as Sexual (low)"

Evidently, sex is among the top services.
